# Does mongo-hadoop support replacing documents?

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop

I'm trying to replace (not update with $set) documents in MongoDB using mongo-hadoop in Spark (mongo-hadoop-core-1.4.2.jar & mongo-java-driver-3.2.1.jar) :

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("_id", 6972);

BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
update.append("_id", 6988);
update.append("f1", "ACTIVE_USER");
```

Then I'm writing something like this :

```
new MongoUpdateWritable(query, update, false, true);
```

But this is failing with :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name f1
```

I can do :

```
new MongoUpdateWritable(query, new BasicDBObject("$set", update), false, true);
```

But I want to replace the whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
mongo-hadoop [added support](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-263) for replacing documents in [2.0.0-rc0](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/releases/tag/r2.0.0-rc0). From then on, to replace a document entirely, you'll have to use

```
new MongoUpdateWritable(query, update, false/*or true*/, false, true)
```

Note: you can't use replacing and `multiUpdate = true` together, and replacing also doesn't change the `_id` value - see [Replace a Document Entirely](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#replace-a-document-entirely):

> The `update()` method *does not* replace the `_id` value.
>   ...
>   `update()` *cannot* update multiple documents.

---

<strike>Looking at the code, that doesn't seem to be possible: `MongoOutputCommitter` always issues an update command (that can only contain `$operators`) - see [MongoOutputCommitter.java line 155](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/r1.4.2/core/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/output/MongoOutputCommitter.java#L155) and below. They use `BulkUpdateRequestBuilder`'s `update` / `updateOne` methods, but to issue a replace command they need to use `replaceOne` method.

So, no such feature.</strike> Maybe you'll make a pull request :)

Comment: Thanks @Roman. I'll probably raise a feature request on their JIRA or maybe do a pull request for a weekend project !